# NDK, why it is missing SDK features?

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

Let's say we are talking about android. Why NDK is missing SDK features? for example, why there is no support of bluetooth in NDK or why some useful libraries are missing? NDK code runs directly on your processor, you are able to deal with wifi, networking but you cant handle bluetooth, they just seem to be different parts of a chip, nothing special about them.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not the way you are suppose to use the NDK.

Read the [NDK homepage](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) from google. The NDK is here to be used for really specific task.

If you can do what you need with the Android SDK, you should always use the Android SDK, not the NDK.